# The network path was not found.This connection has not been restored

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I have a VPN that I use to connect to my work's network when I am in the field or at home.  I frequently get the message:

> Microsoft Windows Network: The network path was not found. The
>   connection has not been restored.

At first I thought it was my Wi-Fi connection, as it isn't the best, but I have been able to connect occasionally at home. I have gotten this error when using my phone's hotspot and on other Wi-Fi connections as well. I have tried forcing a connection through the cmd window, but that doesn't always work either.

Anyone have any thoughts as to what might be giving me this error?

Comment: The network path on the VPN cannot be found so perhaps you're having VPN connectivity issues when this occurs?